# Installing Mesa OpenCL for Nvidia?

Tags: nvidia, nouveau, mesa, opencl

Out of curiosity, I've tried to install OpenCL on my Ubuntu 21.04 installation.

I believe there may be OpenCL 1.1 support available in the open-source Nouveau video driver for Nvidia graphics cards. This is the driver I'm using (and am stuck with).

My Nvidia hardware is a dated 9400 GT card, but an upgrade to a 9800 GT is possible.

```
$ sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd    # Install opencl, ICD and compilers.

$ sudo usermod -a -G video username   # Add me to the video group for display access.

$ sudo clinfo
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 21.0.1
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Clover
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No devices found in platform [Clover?]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.14
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 3.0
```

So, as you can see I'm clueless. What I'm really after is someone who can direct me to appropriate resources, so that I can learn how to setup mesa's OpenCL implementation, as well as how to invoke and use the associated compilers, ICD, etc.?

Any help would be appreciated.

M.

Tried a bunch of other stuff: Checked that /etc/OpenCL/vendors/*.dri file is there, and filled-in correctly. All the requisite packages and files are in place. Why it can't see my GPU, I'm clueless about.

Answer (score 0):

It appears my particular Nvidia GPU was not yet supported at 31/07/21.

To check progress on support for your GPU, consult https://mesamatrix.net/#OpenCL.

Thanks to all those who viewed my query.

M.